# Send email with attachment django

Tags: python, django, email

I have the file url in my db. I want to send the file as an attachment in email. I have tried the below code

```
def mail_business_plan(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ctx = {"ctx":instance}

        from_email = 'info@some_email.in'

        subject = 'Business Plan by' + instance.company_name
        message = get_template('email/business_team.html').render(ctx)
        to = ['some_email@gmail.com']
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)
        mail.attach_file(instance.presentation, instance.presentation.read(), instance.presentation.content_type)
        return mail.send()
```

I am getting error as "AttributeError: 'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'content_type'"

What's the best way to send mail with attachment, if the file path is stored in the database.

Comment: what is instance  model? exactly presentation field?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a model as,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # other fields
    presentation = models.FileField(upload_to='some/place/')
```

and in your *signals*,

```
import mimetypes


def mail_business_plan(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ctx = {"ctx": instance}

        from_email = 'info@some_email.in'

        subject = 'Business Plan by' + instance.company_name
        message = get_template('email/business_team.html').render(ctx)
        to = ['some_email@gmail.com']
        mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)

        content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(instance.presentation.name)[0] # change is here <<<
        mail.attach_file(instance.presentation, instance.presentation.read(), content_type) # <<< change is here also

        return mail.send()
```

**Reference:**
[`mimetypes.guess_type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to send email in python is using smtp

Here are the steps to configure postfix in ubuntu and send mail.

1. `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

   just press ok for all the popup (you can change the hostname later)
2. `sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf`

   change the following line `from inet_interfaces = all` to `inet_interfaces = localhost`
3. `sudo service postfix restart`

Try the following code after you done with all these steps

```
import os.path
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

def send_email(subject, message, from_email, to_email=[], attachment=[]):
    """
    :param subject: email subject
    :param message: Body content of the email (string), can be HTML/CSS or plain text
    :param from_email: Email address from where the email is sent
    :param to_email: List of email recipients, example: ["a@a.com", "b@b.com"]
    :param attachment: List of attachments, exmaple: ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
    """
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(to_email)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))

    for f in attachment:
        with open(f, 'rb') as a_file:
            basename = os.path.basename(f)
            part = MIMEApplication(a_file.read(), Name=basename)

        part[
            'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename
        msg.attach(part)

    email = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    email.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by changing

```
mail.attach_file(instance.presentation, instance.presentation.read(), instance.presentation.content_type)
```

to

```
mail.attach_file(instance.presentation.path)
```