# Python Django send_mail function

Tags: python, django, function, email

Is there any way to send an attachment with the send_mail() function from Django?

And if not, could someone please send me a link to a module that has this possibility.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720968/send-email-with-attachment-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yeah, you can:**

```
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage()
email.subject = "New shirt submitted"
email.body = html_message
email.from_email = "ThatAwesomeShirt! <no-reply@thatawesomeshirt.com>"
email.to = [ "somefakeaddress@hotmail.com", ] <p></p>
 # Attach a file directly
email.attach_file("img.jpg")

# Or alternatively, if you want to attach the contents directly

file = open("img.jpg", "rb")
email.attach(filename = "hellokitty.jpg", mimetype = "image/jpeg", content = file.read())
file.close()

email.send()
```

Comment: But where should I add the password? Or is the password I've set in the settings.py automatically taken? And are those <p></p> necessary?

Comment: yeah, the password you've set in settings.py. <p></p> isn't necessary, its optional to give a style to the message